# How to get a cv::Mat to 2 by 2 maximum value mean?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

```
0, 1, 0, 0 ,0, 0

0, 0, 2, 0 ,4, 0

0, 1, 0, 5 ,0, 0

0, 0, 1, 0 ,1, 0

0, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 0
```

I am using opencv.
Assume that cv: mat data is the same as the above array.

I want to get the average of the maximum of 2 by 2 of the array.

As great as

```
           2, 0 
           0, 5
```

It will be.
We will divide this value by four to get the average.

How do you get the maximum of 2 by 2?

Comment: Surely `0, 4, 5, 0` is larger?

Comment: for each 2x2 window, compute the mean and save it in a result Mat in the upper-left pixel position of your window (maybe with a 2x2 filter or two separated 1D filter). Afterwards, search the maximum in that result Mat with findMinMaxLoc function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use blur filter like

```
cv::gaussianblur(input_mat,output_mat,cv::size(5,5),0);
```

Comment: try it and tell me